# Python - Interacting with GUI elements across multiple modules

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I have a GUI built in python that I would like to move to it's own module. However I am running into issues when interacting with the GUI elements as well as importing them correctly. (Example code below)

I believe the issue is partially that the gui module does not finish importing before being used inside main. If I were to use a third module with the active code to start it, the GUI would be functional but then I am unsure how to reference the GUI widgets from inside the 'main' methods absent the app object.

My question is mainly that of what is the recommended way to implement an interactive GUI with many widgets. Am I completely off track trying to split it up among different modules? In my actual project if I put it all inside a single module it's running over several thousand lines of code already and I am not yet finished adding features.

EDIT: The specific problem in the below example is the failure of the button command with error of "'main' is not defined". Switching that to only the function name similarly gives the error "'testButton' is not defined"

gui.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class AppGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()

        self.master.minsize(self.master.winfo_reqwidth(), self.master.winfo_reqheight()) 
        self.master.resizable(False,False) 
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit_callback)

        self.create_frames()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_frames(self):
        self.r0c0 = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=100, bg="grey")
        self.r0c0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw", padx=5, pady=5)
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.testButton = tk.Button(
          master=self.r0c0, text="testButton",
          command=lambda: main.testButton("testing"),
          ).pack()
        self.outputTextBox = tk.Text(master=self.r0c0)
        self.outputTextBox.pack()
import main
```

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk

def testButton(phrase):
  tmp = app.outputTestBox.get("1.0", tk.END)
  print(tmp)
  app.outputTestBox.insert("0.0","testing: "+phrase+"\n")

import gui
##Begin Gui##
window = tk.Tk()
app = gui.AppGUI(master=window)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This seems like a code style question and might be a better fit somewhere else in the network. That or I missed the solvable question.  Code is normally split without issue across many files, independant of the type of code, is really the answer IMO.

Comment: @TankorSmash, My apologies I was not particularly clear. In the example code above when the test button on the GUI is clicked the executed lambda will fail with the error "main not defined"

I am also concerned I am making serious errors in structuring (Circular imports seem a bit weird) so if you could point me where in the network the style resources are located that would be a great help.

Comment: in gui. py, why **import main** is the last line?? it should be the 1st or 2nd along with **import tkinter as tk**

Comment: also if the button or widget name is the same as its command name or exactly its function name, on-click the function will not run and without any traceback or debug info, those are few errors i made and learned during my tkinter project. Hence **testButton** is the widget name, rename button' command function to smthg else such as **def testing**

Comment: last but not least, to import another file, it should be always in the top along with other imports. i gave you all actual hints i know. hopefully it will help.

Comment: Usually any functionality of the gui shouldn't really be defined on the same .py file as the gui itself, so better to just add the functionality in main.py and remove the import main from gui.py (circular import). I believe you do this in tkinter by `app.testButton["command"] = lambda: testButton("testing")`. There are some other things about your code I don't understand either (like what is self.quit_callback) but does that help in any way?

Comment: @CYREX The import statements at the bottom allows circular importing so retrieved file from the import cache is not empty when they reference each other.

Comment: @Rolv Thanks! That sounds like a much better option compared to what i've been trying. I'll test it out tomorrow and see if it does what I need. I copied a few sections of my code and changed the naming for the example. self.quit_callback is my exit handling method that I missed deleting before posting sorry.